# ui grid show hyperlink on export excel cell

Tags: excel-formula, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I want to change this

```
var cell = {
            v: value,
            s: {alignment: {horizontal:"left"}}
        };
```

to add hyperlink formula on 'value' like this

```
`{ formula:'HYPERLINK("' + mainhyperlinkurl + '","Download.Zip")' };`
```

In the below addcell function code sample

```
function addCell(range, value, row, col, ws, isHeader) {
        if (range.s.r > row) range.s.r = row;
        if (range.s.c > col) range.s.c = col;
        if (range.e.r < row) range.e.r = row;
        if (range.e.c < col) range.e.c = col;
        var cell = {
            v: value,
            s: {alignment: {horizontal:"left"}}
        };
        if (cell.v == null) cell.v = '-';
        var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({
            c: col,
            r: row
        });

        //if (typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
        //if (!isNaN(cell.v)) cell.t = 'n'; 
        //else 
        if (typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
        else if (cell.v instanceof Date) {
            cell.t = 'n';
            cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
            cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
        } else cell.t = 's';
        if(isHeader){
            cell.s = {
                font: {
                    bold:isHeader
                }
            };
        }
        ws[cell_ref] = cell;
    }
```

waiting for your response, Thanks.